# how to make changes to a single li instead of all of them using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

all the `<li>`s have a span with the class of "x" and i want to toggle the "x" class to the specific `<span>` that corresponds to the `<li>` over which I am hovering, not to all of them

I can't do this:

```
$("div ul li").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
        $("span").toggleClass("x")
    })
```

because  it toggles the class for all the `<span>`s

I am thinking that I should use the keyword `this`, but I don't know how to do something like, hypothetically, `$(this)."span"`, or `$($(this)."span")`. I need to find out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be what you need is using [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/). Example:

```
$("div ul li").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).find("span").toggleClass("x")
})
```